# Kentico form - captions inside form element

Tags: forms, kentico

I am guessing this is really simple but I haven't been able to work out a solution.

I have created a form in Kentico and need to show the caption in the form element itself. I can do this in bootstrap but cannot seem to get this to work in the form editor. I am guessing this is because of the id kentico assigns to each form element.

An example would be the search box used on the stackoverflow site.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

When configuring some text field and form control is Text box under Editing control settings click 'Advanced' you will see the Watermark section, where you can put your caption (Text field). This caption will be displayed in form element.

[image]

Comment: I knew it would be simple. Thanks for answering this.

Comment: Make sure to mark his answer as the correct one, helps us all out!